# How to reply to a celery task without celery?

Tags: java, python, celery

I'm using celery to send a task to a Java worker.  The worker isn't using celery, but the docs were clear enough that I can parse the request json to get the task name, args, etc.  Now I'm trying to reply to the request.  I thought it may be as easy as sticking the reply into a queue with the `task.properties.reply_to` name, but that's not working.

How do you reply to a task?

BTW, I'm using redis for both the broker and backend.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using Celery's [WebHook interface](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html). That is designed to allow systems written in other languages to run Celery tasks.

Django example:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from anyjson import serialize


def multiply(request):
    x = int(request.GET['x'])
    y = int(request.GET['y'])
    result = x * y
    response = {'status': 'success', 'retval': result}
    return HttpResponse(serialize(response), mimetype='application/json')
```

Comment: FYI this feature is from version 2.4.7 celery. today celery is on 5.2. i do not see this feature in version 5.2 or 5.1 celery.